# how To add application name on the top android application in which pagesrTitleStrip is used

Tags: android

i am creating a android application for a news website activity_main.xml has the following code

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:id="@+id/pager"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context=".MainActivity" >



<!--

This title strip will display the currently visible page title, as well as the page

titles for adjacent pages.

-->


<android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip


    android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="235px"

    android:layout_gravity="top"

    android:background="#33b5e5"

    android:paddingBottom="4dp"

    android:paddingTop="4dp"

    android:textColor="#fff" />
```

this helps me to swipe the diffent pages i accomplish this by writing the following code in `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three

    // primary sections of the app.

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


}


@Override

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;

}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {

        super(fm);

    }



    @Override

    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment fragment2=new Fragment();

        switch(position)

        {

        case 0:

            Fragment1 fragment=new Fragment1();

            return (Fragment) fragment;


        case 1:


            Fragment2 fragment1=new Fragment2();


            return fragment1;



        default:break;

        }

        return fragment2;

    }



    @Override


    public int getCount() {


        // Show 3 total pages.


        return 4;


    }


    @Override


    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {


        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();

        switch (position) {


        case 0:


            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);


        case 1:


            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);

        case 2:

            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);


        case 3:


            return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);


        }

        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */

public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";


    public DummySectionFragment() {

    }


    @Override


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);

        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);

        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));

        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

by using above code i can nevigate through 4 child pages session1,session2,session3,session4

but i am not able to give a common title(name off app) to the in the top which is common to all sessions.

so please give me sollution to my problem.it is better if i am able to set a backgroung of a PagerTitleStrip as a image

Comment: set same value (title you want) to all your strings `R.string.title_section1 & R.string.title_section2 & R.string.title_section3 & R.string.title_section4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to set same value (title you want) to all your strings `R.string.title_section1` & `R.string.title_section2` & `R.string.title_section3` & `R.string.title_section4` or you can also use only one string at all places, choice is yours.